# Responsive web design using angular js

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design

What is the best practice to use angular js in responsive web development. Media query is already implemented but the stuff we do in js like windo.resize and all. How to implement the same using angular js.Is there any angular way ?

Answer (score 0):

there are two main options :

1. Angular UI Bootstrap : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
2. Angular Material : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

You should find some doc by following the links.